# How do I get overflow-y to produce a vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achive the effect where I have a vertical scroll bar around the outer div and the horizontal content spills out of it.

To do this I have been setting the overflow-y to auto in my style.css:

```
.outerdiv {
    background-color:brown;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="outerdiv">
      <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
      <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
      <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
      <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
   </div>
<body>
</html>
```

But this shows both the vertical and horizontal scrollbar.

How do I get rid of the horizontal scrollbar and have the inner content (i.e. the xxx's) spill out of the right hand side of the outerdiv container and just have a vertical scrollbar?

Please see this plunker example: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZTODuxvaAv4XN4hGHWu9?p=preview

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a third-party site.

Comment: slightly off topic, sorry: I wonder why those linked Plunker pages never show anything here except the headline (as in this case, but also in every other Plunker page that's linked in SO). Do you have to be registered there to see anything? (I am on Firefox Mac, if that is relevant)

Answer (score 1):

You just set the overflow-x to hidden:

```
.outerdiv {
    background-color:brown;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this hides the horizontal overflowing content.  I'd like for it to spill out of the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the horizontal scrollbar with this:

```
.outerdiv {
    background-color: brown;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

But to have the extra text spill off to the side rather than the bottom while maintaining a vertical scrollbar appears to cause a conflict. It stoutly refuses to render horizontally overflowing text outside of the content area if a scroll bar is in the way, instead forcing a horizontal scroll bar.

It may be possible to get around this limitation by scripting an unofficial scrollbar though JavaScript and scroll events.